# Best way to search an 8 character string for words in AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3

I apologise before hand if this has been answered, but I had a look and couldn't find exactly what I was looking for.

I'm looking for the best way to search an 8 char string in AS3 to see if it contains a word or words. I've already got a dictionary of words loaded into Flash, with...

```
[Embed(source = "../f-16.txt",mimeType = "application/octet-stream")]
private static const wordFile:Class;
var words:Array = new wordFile().toString().split("\n");
```

I was thinking of splitting that up further into 26 arrays for each starting letter, and than possibly those arrays up into arrays of varying length words (so all the 8 letters words starting with a are together, and so on).

What I need to do is search an 8 char string in AS3 to see if it contains any word or words from the dictionary array. Below are some example strings and what I would need returned...

1. "beenpoet" = "been","poet"
2. "itxitxit" = "it","it","it"
3. "aardvark" = "aardvark"

and so on. The problem I can see is that words can start at any point in the string which complicates matters.

What would be the best (fastest) way to do that in as3?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: How does "catscat" (or things like that) split?

Comment: Are you looking for a general algorithm, or is there something specific to AS3 that you are having trouble with?

Comment: Specific to AS3 would be more useful, but basically just the most efficient way to do that. I'm sure I could come up with some kind of code to do that, but some advice on the best way to do it would be helpful, so I don't go off in the wrong direction :)

Answer (score 3):

I'm...

I'm a little drunk. (This might get deleted by the SO mods.) (Edit: I'm very drunk.)

However, for your specific use case....

> I'm looking for the best way to search an 8 char string in AS3 to see
>   if it contains a word or words. I've already got a dictionary of words
>   loaded into Flash, with...
>
> I was thinking of splitting that up further into 26 arrays for each
>   starting letter, and than possibly those arrays up into arrays of
>   varying length words (so all the 8 letters words starting with a are
>   together, and so on).

I might suggest a tree structure - this means that you'd have 26^8 combinations of letters. I would imagine that would be a quicker search than an Array lookup, since you wouldn't have to iterate through the array to find your value.

Each character of your string will be a layer of your tree. Ideally, you'll be able to stop well before you hit the max branch. Your maximum lookup would be 26^8, whatever that number is.

The best thing about this approach is that with the tree structure, recursing along the tree should be trivial in terms of writing code. You only have to store the dictionary words. As such, if someone types "cbyir", you'll know (by the second character) that the input doesn't match a dictionary word. (Unless there is a word that starts with CB. Oh Webster, where art thou?)

Another benefit of this - you can easily check each character of your string. If the proceeding character does not match (or the third, or the fourth...), you can discard that search and exit early; your function doesn't need to be naive.

Again, I am drunk. I wish you the best of luck, though! :-D If you have any questions, please comment, as I know this might not be clear.

Edit: I came back to this answer, because I was thinking about it. A possible implementation could make use of the AS3 Dictionary class; you could have Dictionaries pointing to Dictionaries. This would be much faster than an array lookup, as lookup time is O(1) for dictionaries. This means that your tree lookup would be really, really *fast* - the number of iterations would be equal to the number of letters in your word, not the number of possible combinations of letters in your word.

Give something like this a shot; I'm pretty sure it will work. If you have any implementation questions, let me know.

Comment: Thanks, that's an interesting way of doing it, although I havn't a clue how to program a search tree, also would it be able to deal with multiple words in the same string? Hope you're not feeling too hung over! :)

Comment: @Phil Multiple words shouldn't be a problem. You simply run the search algorithm starting with each letter in the string, not just the beginning one. You can prune possibilities once they are no longer valid. And yes, this morning's going to be rough. :P

Comment: I've never used the dictionary class, any simple code to show how it can be used in this case?

Comment: @Phil - I can whip something up, but it'll take a bit.

Comment: No problem, I was just curious how you would implement the dictionary class in this situation. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```
public class WordFinder {

   public var searchFor:Array = [];

   public function search(value:String):Array {
      var result:Array=[];
      for each (var word:String in searchFor) {
         if (value.indexOf(word) >= 0) {
            result.push(word);
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you need to do:

```
public function verifyWord(word : String, wordList : Array) : Array
{
    var resultArray : Array = [];
    for(var i : int = 0; i < word.length; i++)
    {
        for(var j : int = word.length; j > i; j--)
        {
            var brokenWord : String = word.substring(i, j);
            if(wordList.indexOf(brokenWord) >= 0)  // We are performing a search on a array, so its O(n), super slow, change this for something good
            {
                resultArray.push(brokenWord);
            }
        }
    }
    return resultArray;
}
```

Basically:

- Split the input word into every possible combination;
- For each splited word, you need to verify if the dictionary has them (currently using array search, which is SLOW);
- To increase performance, you can either store the dictionary as a hashtable or use a half-interval or smarter search algorithm to check if the word is in the dictionary or not (see this [AS3: Large text files with indexOf() on an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8099543/as3-large-text-files-with-indexof-on-an-array))